# How to use Pandas to update multiple excel files and save the updated files without combinig them

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have multiple excel files containing several sheets. I need to remove some specific columns from a particular sheet. I need to do the same for all the files. After that I need to save all those edited files without combinig them. I have done the same for one file, I need a macro so that I can apply for all the files.
I have prepared the code for one file:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
sheet = book['sheet1']
#the update needed is to delete some columns
sheet.delete.cols(3,5)    
book.save('file1_copy.xlsx')
```

Comment: This doesn't involve Pandas at all. However you could accomplish the same with `pandas.read_excel`

Comment: @Davis using pandas may cause issues as pandas parses the actual `xml` and creates a new excel object - with no formatting, whereas openpyxl will save the formatting (i think!)

Comment: @Umar.H Cool, did not know that. The title and tags should probably be updated then

Comment: Pandas uses openpyxl to read and write XLSX files.

Answer (score 0):

as you've already written the code, all that is left is to iterate over your files and apply it one by one.

I would do this as follows :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pathlib import Path

excel_files = Path('excel_file_location').glob('*.xlsx')

for file in excel_files:
   book = load_workbook(file)
   sheet = book['sheet1']
   #the update needed is to delete some columns
   sheet.delete.cols(3,5)    
   # save in same location with the _copy suffix attached. 
   # /home/file/excel_1.xlsx -> /home/file/excel_1_copy.xlsx 
   book.save(f"{file.parent}{file.stem}_copy{file.suffix}")
```

Comment: Thanks Umar for the solution.. Can you please tell me what is file.parent, file.stem and file.suffix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list with all the files and then loop over that list. That will run the code in the `for` loop for each item in the list. You'll also have to have the code adjust the new save name.

So you'd have something like

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
books = ['file1.xlsx', 'file2.xlsx', 'file3.xlsx',...]
for book in books:
    sheet = book['sheet1']
    sheet.delete.cols(3,5)
    savename = book.split('.')[0] + '_copy.' + book.split('.')[-1]
    book.save(savename)
```